# JSF ViewState and asynchronous Ajax-Requests

Tags: ajax, spring, jsf, asynchronous

I have a page where I add dynamic tabs From a bean TabView And do some asychronous actions.

```
<h:form id="requestForm">
                    <p:panel id="requestPanel" header="SQL"
                        styleClass="noBorder">
                        <p:remoteCommand name="updateMainForm" process=":requestForm" actionListener="#{tabbedView.update()}" update="#{tabbedView.idsToUpdate}"/>
                        <p:tabView id="myTabPanel" binding="#{tabbedView.tabview}" />
                        <f:facet name="actions">
                            <p:commandButton value="Ajout Onglet" icon="fa faw fa-plus grey" actionListener="#{tabbedView.add}" 
                                process=":requestForm" update="requestForm" async="true"
                                styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon white secondBtn" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
```

Bean method to add tabs

```
@Async
public void add() {
    System.out.println("Begin add");
    Tab newTab = new Tab();
    controllers.add(controller);
    newTab.setTitle("Onglet "+tabs.size());
    newTab.setId("tab"+tabs.size());
    System.out.println("Finish add");
    newTab.getChildren().add(createForm(tabs.indexOf(newTab)));
    this.tabview.getChildren().add(newTab);
}
```

Using async=true, each method is runing asynchronous and each component is loaded once its available, but then only the component that was ready last is working. All other Components are lost.
Is there a way to sove this ?

Comment: Just don't use `async=true` if you want to keep view state in sync?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot dynamically add tabs without updating the full tab component ( I know you update the full component, so my comment is not about you doing something wrong). Being able to just add a tab  would solve the problem I think. This is simply (and unfortunately) a 'missing feature' in PrimeFaces. Please file an issue for this since I personally think it is a very useful feature.

Comment: @BalusC How can I run bean method asynchronous with no async=true ?

Comment: Depends on the X-problem you're trying to solve with this http://xyproblem.info